# Show that $\{ f^{-1}(E) : E \in σ(S)\} = \sigma \{f^{-1}(E) : E ∈ S\}$.

Tags: measure-theory

Given a collection of subsets of a set $X$ let $\sigma$(S) denote the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $S$. Let $X, Y$ be sets, $f : X → Y$ and $S$ be a collection of
subsets of $Y$ . Show that $\{f^{-1}(E) : E \in\sigma(S)\} = \sigma\{f^{-1}(E) : E \in S\}$.

I have already shown that both of these sets are $\sigma$-algebras, so this is not an issue. I have also shown that  $B = \{E \subset Y : f^{-1}(E) \in X1\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ (where $X_1$ is the first set). I wanted to use this to say that is $S \subset B$ and $B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra implies that $\sigma$(S) $\subset$ B and thus show that A $\in$ X$_1$ implies A $\in$ X$_2$. I don't really know if this is correct or how to go about finishing it so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, to display the formulas and math symbols, put the expression within two $

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal A=\{f^{-1} (E):E \in \sigma (S)\}$ and $\mathcal B=\sigma \{f^{-1} (E):E \in S\}$. Consider $\{E \in \sigma (S): f^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal B\}$. This is a sigma algebra which contains $S$. Hence it contains $\sigma (S)$. This proves that $\mathcal A \subseteq \mathcal B$. The other inclusion is simple: $\{f^{-1} (E):E \in S\} \subseteq \mathcal A$ and $\mathcal A$ is a sigma algbra. Hence $\mathcal B \subseteq \mathcal A$.